# How to use the C++ standalone ASIO library

Tags: c++, windows, asio

I am trying to use the asio library on Windows 10, here is a simple test code block:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <asio.hpp>

using std::cout;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello asio\n";
    asio::io_context ioc;
    asio::steady_timer tmer(ioc, asio::chrono::seconds(1));
    tmer.wait();

    cout << "hi asio\n";
    ioc.run();

    return 0;
}
```

with Visual Studio 2017. To open a developer command prompt, I use the following command

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\Tools>vsdevcmd`

Then, based on the [asio doc](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.12.2/doc/asio/using.html), I run the command `nmake -f Makefile.msc` under the asio src folder. But I am getting an error:

```
Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.16.27025.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -Fetests\latency\tcp_client.exe -Fotests\latency\tcp_client.obj -nologo -EHac -GR -I. -I../include    -O2 -MD        -I../../boost_1_34_1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501  -DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB  -DBOOST_CHRONO_DONT_PROVIDE_HYBRID_ERROR_HANDLING tests\latency\tcp_client.cpp  -link -opt:ref
tcp_client.cpp
../include\asio/detail/config.hpp(26): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'boost/config.hpp': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

It seems the library requires boost/config.hpp. I really trying to avoid to use the boost. Is there a way I could use the asio standalone on windows 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to use vcpkg, but it turns out I only need to download the library and create a cmake file to do the job.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(asio)
add_definitions(-DASIO_STANDALONE -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501) 
# -DBOOST_DATE_TIME_NO_LIB -DBOOST_REGEX_NO_LIB)
# include_directories(${VCPKG_DIR}//asio_x86-windows//include)
include_directories(./../libs/asio-1.12.2/include)
add_executable(asio s5.cpp)
```

Answer (score 1):

To use asio without any boost libraries, you have to define `ASIO_STANDALONE` at some point. The best would be in your Visual Studio project, or in your code before any include of asio header.

Answer (score 0):

Following command line seems to work. It would be nice addition to boost.asio standalone documentation.

$ nmake STANDALONE=1 -f Makefile.msc

I took me some time to figure out this since I have never used NMAKE even though I have developed a lot of stuff to Windows with MS compiler. It is very not-so-good tool for MAKE process.

Although the make command just executes tests. No lib is generated. Just include headers...